# Use checkbox to determine image class

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to use the image associated with the checkbox to change class depending on if it is checked or not, but for some reason it will not change the class.

Code:

```js
$('#providers_netflixNO').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#netflixNOLogo").removeClass("logoNotChecked").addClass("logoChecked");
    return;
  }
  $("#netflixNOLogo").removeClass("logoChecked").addClass("logoNotChecked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="providers" id="providers_netflixNO" value="netflixNO">
  <img src="http://www.streamjunkie.no/images/providers/netflixNO/Logo.jpg" id="netflixNOLogo" class="logoNotChecked">
</label>
```

Comment: Its working for me: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2ykxhyyx/)

Comment: Your code can be in fact shortened: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2ykxhyyx/1/)

Comment: Any errors in your console? jQuery included? No duplicated IDs?

Comment: I get the following error in console:
konto:239 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` that means jQuery is not loaded. Make sure you have jQuery available before you try to use it.

Comment: @MatsDanielsen you have to include the jQuery library in your page first: [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

Comment: I have been able to get rid of the error, but still no success with the actual usage, could you please check it out at the website URL? [link](http://www.streamjunkie.no/konto)